# SQL query with multiple same conditions

Tags: sql, select, sybase

I work with Sybase DB and trying to select data using few conditions:

The table name "alias".

```
a_id, a_data, a_type_id, a_value
------------------------------
    1,   666,       123, "value_1"
    2,   666,       456, "value_2"
    3,   777,       123, "value_4"
    4,   777,       456, "value_5"
```

---

I have few conditions:

```
1. a_type_id = 123 and a_value = "value_1" AND
2. a_type_id = 456 and a_value = "value_2"
```

So the result should be `a_data = 666`, in case the both conditions are achived.
The query should be like this, but it, of course, does not work, returns 0 results:

```
select a_data from alias where ( a_type_id = 123 AND a_value = "value_1" ) AND (a_type_id = 456 AND a_value = "value_2")
```

Expecting result `a_data = 666`.

Can someone advise something workaround? It is possible to have 2, 3 or more conditions like above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation and `having`:

```
select a_data
from t
where (a_type_id = 123 and a_value = 'value_1') or
      (a_type_id = 456 and a_value = 'value_2')
group by a_data
having count(*) = 2;
```

Note:  This assumes that type/value pairs are not duplicated in the original data for a given `a_data` value.  If they can be, then use:

```
having count(distinct a_type_id) = 2
```

Comment: That works, thank you! And yes, type/value pairs can be duplicated for different a_data values. So I should use 'having count(distinct a_type_id) = 2', so it will be possible to get few result values.

Comment: I wonder if there are any other ability to do a such query? I used it on the veeery huge db table - and it took about 3 seconds. It has low productivity.I know, that the table isn't optimized properly, but is there any chanse to speed up it somehow?

Comment: @AlexandrDerkach . . . I would recommend an index on `(a_type_id, a_value, a_data)`.

Comment: Yeah, that should help as well